# Can recursion be replaced with a finite set of higher-order functions?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, lambda-calculus

I am wondering if there is some proof that all recursive algorithms can be rewritten to use some known set of higher-order functions instead of recursion. I'm talking about functions like fold, map, filter, etc.

If recursion *can* always be replaced, I'm also interested in knowing whether there is some mechanical translation, or if it's something that can't be automated.

Apologies if this question is ill-formed. I'm no PLT expert.

Comment: Are you looking for Kleene normal form?

Comment: You could always use the [Y combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus) which is sufficient to simulate all recursion...

Comment: Does it matter that `fold`, `map`, `filter`, etc. are themselves defined by (structural) recursion? And would you consider it cheating if I suggested that all you need is `fix : (t -> t) -> t` which computes fixed points?

Comment: Can we migrate this to cs.computerscience.com?

Comment: I am not sure about Kleene normal form, but the others were correct to guess that I was lacking basic knowledge about fixed-point combinators. Incidentally, I don't care whether or not the higher order functions are defined by structural recursion. But I'm going to go away and read more before thinking about this. Thanks guys.

Comment: Also I don't know what cs.computerscience.com is, or whether that question was addressed to me.

Comment: Oops, I meant cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may replace recursion with computation of fixed points, so all you need is a fixed-point operator

```
fix : (a -> a) -> a
```

which satisfies

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

Then, given a recursive definition of `f : a -> b`,

```
f = Φ(f)
```

we may define `f` as

```
f = fix (λg.Φ(g))
```

Here `fix` has type `((a -> b) -> (a -> b)) -> (a -> b)`.

You may consider this to be cheating, but the question is not really research-level precisely because the connection between recursion and fixed points is a basic piece of knowledge. I am guessing that maybe you did not know about the connection.

Comment: Thank you! I studied this about 8 years ago, and since I haven't looked at he subject since I had indeed forgotten the connection. Maybe I'll return when I've figured out what I'm really trying to ask, but this answer is definitely the starting point I was looking for.